# nginx php5-fpm doesn't show PHP message

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I looked in my nginx error.log and saw that it is overfilled with these errors:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message:" while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET /forum HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "...", referrer: "..."
```

As you can see there is no message where the error is thrown.

What is the reason why no message is shown there?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after almost one year I've fixed the error some months ago. The problem was that I've enabled the gzip compression in nginx and also in my CMS Joomla. I had only on a few pages with a failure (Encoding Error) in the backend. Now I've disabled the gzip compression on Joomla and everything works right. No more errors every few seconds in my log.

I hope this could help someone.